# Background-image gradient not working

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to modify the default ASP.NET MVC4 website template, but I can't figure out why my css isn't working. It's probably a rookie mistake. I've been searching and trying to fix it for hours now, but I can't figure it out.

The gradient works in the footer, but not inside the header. I'd like everything from the black border to the main content(everything inside the header element) to have it's background as one big gradient. Even the backup background-color doesn't work, however it(color, not gradient) does work when I size my browser window down to mobile-size. Any ideas?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Home Page - Test</title>
        <link href="/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

        <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <div class="float-left">
                    <p class="site-title"><a href="/">Test</a></p>
                </div>
                <div class="float-right">
                    <section id="login">
                       Hei, <span class="username">Anonymous</span>!
                    </section>
                    <nav>
                        <ul id="menu">
                            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/Home/About">About</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/Home/Contact">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div id="body">
            <!---->
            <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">


<h3>We suggest the following:</h3>
<ol class="round">
    <li class="one">
        <h5>Getting Started</h5>
        ASP.NET MVC gives you a powerful, patterns-based way to build dynamic websites that
        enables a clean separation of concerns and that gives you full control over markup
        for enjoyable, agile development. ASP.NET MVC includes many features that enable
        fast, TDD-friendly development for creating sophisticated applications that use
        the latest web standards.
        <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=245151">Learn more…</a>
    </li>

    <li class="two">
        <h5>Add NuGet packages and jump-start your coding</h5>
        NuGet makes it easy to install and update free libraries and tools.
        <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=245153">Learn more…</a>
    </li>

    <li class="three">
        <h5>Find Web Hosting</h5>
        You can easily find a web hosting company that offers the right mix of features
        and price for your applications.
        <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=245157">Learn more…</a>
    </li>
</ol>

            </section>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <div class="float-left">
                    <p>&copy; 2013 - Test</p>
                </div>
                <div class="float-right">
                    <p>Under development. ALPHA</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>

        <!--<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>

        -->


</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html {
    background-color: #e2e2e2;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    /*background-color: #7ac0da;*/
    border-top: solid 10px #000;
    color: #333;
    font-size: .85em;
    font-family: "Segoe UI", Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

a {
    color: #333;
    outline: none;
    padding-left: 3px;
    padding-right: 3px;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

    a:link, a:visited,
    a:active, a:hover {
        color: #333;
    }

/*header, footer, hgroup,
nav, section {
    display: block;
}*/

mark {
    background-color: #a6dbed;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}

.float-left {
    float: left;
}

.float-right {
    float: right;
}

.clear-fix:after {
    content: ".";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}

h1, h2, h3,
h4, h5, h6 {
    color: #000;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 1.75em;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

h4 {
    font-size: 1.1em;
}

h5, h6 {
    font-size: 1em;
}

    h5 a:link, h5 a:visited, h5 a:active {
        padding: 0;
        text-decoration: none;
    }


/* main layout
----------------------------------------------------------*/
.content-wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 960px;
}

header .content-wrapper {
    margin-top: 20px;
    background-color: #7ac0da;
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #7ac0da 0%, #a4d4e6 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, #7ac0da 0%, #a4d4e6 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0, #7ac0da), color-stop(1, #a4d4e6));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #7ac0da 0%, #a4d4e6 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(0% 0% 0deg,#7AC0DA, #a4d4e6);
    /*background-image: linear-gradient(left, #7ac0da 0%, #a4d4e6 100%);*/
}

#body {
    background-color: #efeeef;
    clear: both;
    padding-bottom: 35px;
}

footer {
    clear: both;
    font-size: .8em;
    height: 100px;
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #7ac0da 0%, #a4d4e6 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, #7ac0da 0%, #a4d4e6 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0, #7ac0da), color-stop(1, #a4d4e6));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #7ac0da 0%, #a4d4e6 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(0% 0% 0deg,#7AC0DA, #a4d4e6);
    background-image: linear-gradient(left, #7ac0da 0%, #a4d4e6 100%);
}


/* site title
----------------------------------------------------------*/
.site-title {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Rockwell, Consolas, "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
    font-size: 2.3em;
    margin: 0;
}

.site-title a, .site-title a:hover, .site-title a:active {
    color: #fff;
    outline: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}


/* login
----------------------------------------------------------*/
#login {
    display: block;
    font-size: .85em;
    margin: 0 0 10px;
    text-align: right;
}

    #login a {
        background-color: #d3dce0;
        margin-left: 10px;
        margin-right: 3px;
        padding: 2px 3px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    #login a.username {
        background: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        text-decoration: underline;
    }

    #login ul {
        margin: 0;
    }

    #login li {
        display: inline;
        list-style: none;
    }


/* menu
----------------------------------------------------------*/
ul#menu {
    font-size: 1.3em;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin: 0 0 5px;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: right;
}

    ul#menu li {
        display: inline;
        list-style: none;
        padding-left: 15px;
    }

        ul#menu li a {
            color: #fff;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        ul#menu li a:hover {
            color: #333;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

/* page titles */
hgroup.title {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

hgroup.title h1, hgroup.title h2 {
    display: inline;
}

hgroup.title h2 {
    font-weight: normal;
    margin-left: 3px;
}

/* features */
section.feature {
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
}

/* ordered list */
ol.round {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 0;
}

    ol.round li {
        margin: 25px 0;
        padding-left: 45px;
    }

        ol.round li.zero {
            background: url("../Images/orderedList0.png") no-repeat;
        }

        ol.round li.one {
            background: url("../Images/orderedList1.png") no-repeat;
        }

        ol.round li.two {
            background: url("../Images/orderedList2.png") no-repeat;
        }

        ol.round li.three {
            background: url("../Images/orderedList3.png") no-repeat;
        }

        ol.round li.four {
            background: url("../Images/orderedList4.png") no-repeat;
        }

        ol.round li.five {
            background: url("../Images/orderedList5.png") no-repeat;
        }

        ol.round li.six {
            background: url("../Images/orderedList6.png") no-repeat;
        }

        ol.round li.seven {
            background: url("../Images/orderedList7.png") no-repeat;
        }

        ol.round li.eight {
            background: url("../Images/orderedList8.png") no-repeat;
        }

        ol.round li.nine {
            background: url("../Images/orderedList9.png") no-repeat;
        }

/* content */
article {
    float: left;
    width: 70%;
}

aside {
    float: right;
    width: 25%;
}

    aside ul {
        list-style: none;
        padding: 0;
    }

        aside ul li {
            background: url("../Images/bullet.png") no-repeat 0 50%;
            padding: 2px 0 2px 20px;
        }

.label {
    font-weight: 700;
}

/* login page */
#loginForm {
    border-right: solid 2px #c8c8c8;
    float: left;
    width: 55%;
}

    #loginForm .validation-error {
        display: block;
        margin-left: 15px;
    }

    #loginForm .validation-summary-errors ul {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    #loginForm .validation-summary-errors li {
        display: inline;
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
    }

    #loginForm input {
        width: 250px;
    }

    #loginForm input[type="checkbox"],
    #loginForm input[type="submit"],
    #loginForm input[type="button"],
    #loginForm button {
        width: auto;
    }

#socialLoginForm {
    margin-left: 40px;
    float: left;
    width: 40%;
}

    #socialLoginForm h2 {
        margin-bottom:  5px;
    }

#socialLoginList button {
    margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#logoutForm {
    display: inline;
}

/* contact */
.contact h3 {
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

.contact p {
    margin: 5px 0 0 10px;
}

.contact iframe {
    border: 1px solid #333;
    margin: 5px 0 0 10px;
}

/* forms */
fieldset {
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

    fieldset legend {
        display: none;
    }

    fieldset ol {
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
    }

        fieldset ol li {
            padding-bottom: 5px;
        }

label {
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: 600;
}

label.checkbox {
    display: inline;
}

input, textarea {
    border: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
    background: #fff;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    margin: 5px 0 6px 0;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 300px;
}

textarea {
    font-family: inherit;
    width: 500px;
}

    input:focus, textarea:focus {
        border: 1px solid #7ac0da;
    }

    input[type="checkbox"] {
        background: transparent;
        border: inherit;
        width: auto;
    }

    input[type="submit"],
    input[type="button"],
    button {
        background-color: #d3dce0;
        border: 1px solid #787878;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-size: 1.2em;
        font-weight: 600;
        padding: 7px;
        margin-right: 8px;
        width: auto;
    }

    td input[type="submit"],
    td input[type="button"],
    td button {
        font-size: 1em;
        padding: 4px;
        margin-right: 4px;
    }

/* info and errors */
.message-info {
    border: 1px solid;
    clear: both;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}

.message-error {
    clear: both;
    color: #e80c4d;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 20px 0 10px 0;
}

.message-success {
    color: #7ac0da;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 20px 0 10px 0;
}

.error {
    color: #e80c4d;
}

/* styles for validation helpers */
.field-validation-error {
    color: #e80c4d;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.field-validation-valid {
    display: none;
}

input.input-validation-error {
    border: 1px solid #e80c4d;
}

input[type="checkbox"].input-validation-error {
    border: 0 none;
}

.validation-summary-errors {
    color: #e80c4d;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.1em;
}

.validation-summary-valid {
    display: none;
}


/* tables
----------------------------------------------------------*/
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    margin-top: 0.75em;
    border: 0 none;
}

th {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    text-align: left;
    border: none 0px;
    padding-left: 0;
}

    th a {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
    }

    th a:link, th a:visited, th a:active, th a:hover {
        color: #333;
        font-weight: 600;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 0;
    }

    th a:hover {
        color: #000;
    }

    th.asc a, th.desc a {
        margin-right: .75em;
    }

    th.asc a:after, th.desc a:after {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0em;
        top: 0;
        font-size: 0.75em;
    }

    th.asc a:after {
        content: '▲';
    }

    th.desc a:after {
        content: '▼';
    }

td {
    padding: 0.25em 2em 0.25em 0em;
    border: 0 none;
}

tr.pager td {
    padding: 0 0.25em 0 0;
}


/********************
*   Mobile Styles   *
********************/
@media only screen and (max-width: 850px) {

    /* header
    ----------------------------------------------------------*/
    header .float-left,
    header .float-right {
        float: none;
    }

    /* logo */
    header .site-title {
        margin: 10px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    /* login */
    #login {
        font-size: .85em;
        margin: 0 0 12px;
        text-align: center;
    }

        #login ul {
            margin: 5px 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #login li {
            display: inline;
            list-style: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #login a {
            background: none;
            color: #999;
            font-weight: 600;
            margin: 2px;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #login a:hover {
            color: #333;
        }

    /* menu */
    nav {
        margin-bottom: 5px;
    }

    ul#menu {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        text-align: center;
    }

        ul#menu li {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }


    /* main layout
    ----------------------------------------------------------*/
    .main-content,
    .featured + .main-content {
        background-position: 10px 0;
    }

    .content-wrapper {
        padding-right: 10px;
        padding-left: 10px;
    }

    .featured .content-wrapper {
        padding: 10px;
    }

    /* page content */
    article, aside {
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
    }

    /* ordered list */
    ol.round {
        list-style-type: none;
        padding-left: 0;
    }

        ol.round li {
            padding-left: 10px;
            margin: 25px 0;
        }

            ol.round li.zero,
            ol.round li.one,
            ol.round li.two,
            ol.round li.three,
            ol.round li.four,
            ol.round li.five,
            ol.round li.six,
            ol.round li.seven,
            ol.round li.eight,
            ol.round li.nine {
                background: none;
            }

     /* features */
     section.feature {
        float: none;
        padding: 10px;
        width: auto;
     }

        section.feature img {
            color: #999;
            content: attr(alt);
            font-size: 1.5em;
            font-weight: 600;
        }

    /* forms */
    input {
        width: 90%;
    }

    /* login page */
    #loginForm {
        border-right: none;
        float: none;
        width: auto;
    }

        #loginForm .validation-error {
            display: block;
            margin-left: 15px;
        }

    #socialLoginForm {
        margin-left: 0;
        float: none;
        width: auto;
    }


    /* footer
    ----------------------------------------------------------*/
    footer .float-left,
    footer .float-right {
        float: none;
    }

    footer {
        text-align: center;
        height: auto;
        padding: 10px 0;
    }

        footer p {
            margin: 0;
        }
}
```

Comment: Which browsers are you using - is the issue consistent across browsers?

Comment: IE11 and latest firefox (25, updating to 26 now)

Comment: Seems OK here http://jsfiddle.net/Zp3xa/

Comment: geedubb: even if you make the preview bigger? for me it went to mobile-style as default(gradient didn't work though), but when i resized it to desktop-size it got all grey again

Comment: Ok - I see what you mean now - the window in jsfiddle was too small. I see the grey you are speaking about - no idea what's causing it though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem**

I fixed your issues. Be careful when it comes to `float` these attributes can destroy your layout - if you do not apply propper clearing afterwards. The margin-issue came as you set a margin-top value for the `h3` element which caused the `footer` to be further below. Generally a margin does not affect the actual dimension of an element. Same for the `footer` and the background is only as big as the footer's dimension.

**Find my solution here:**

http://jsfiddle.net/w4Jgh/

**Clearfix**

[What methods of ‘clearfix’ can I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/which-method-of-clearfix-is-best)

http://www.impressivewebs.com/clearing-floats-why-necessary/

Best regards

Comment: Awesome! :) Any good documentation on float and when you need a "clearfix"? Because I can't understand how the float will destroy something outside of it's parent header-elemer. :S

Comment: Everytime you use the float property you need to "clearfix" after the last floated element. You can use a pseudo-selector like in the link I gave you. Float affects the content to "float" around that element so it is within the text-flow. The problem here is that it does not affect the height of your parent-element so it will just "overflow" your container. Also have a look here: http://www.impressivewebs.com/clearing-floats-why-necessary/

Answer (score 1):

Try delete this in the CSS on line 45

```
.float-right {
     float: right;
}
```

Does this make a change in the good direction?

Comment: I does, but it still doesn't cover the small gap between `.menu` and `#body` :-/ The gap over the menu is my bad(margin vs padding), but I can't understand the bottom gap. Also, why would floating affect it? Isn't that just alignment? :S

Comment: I have no clue where this gap comes from. You could use header {margin-bottom: -15px} but that is not a good way to do it.